# PagerDuty Integration

Tags: iframe, backstage, pagerduty

I want to integrate PagerDuty into BackStage using iFrame. Is there an embedded link available in Pagerduty? How can I access it?

I tried using the API plugin, but I want to use iFrames. Just like integrating a youtube video into another platform using iframe.